# Define a custom VBA function that returns blank

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

How do I define an excel function that returns a blank if the result of the formula is blank?

If vlookup finds a blank, it returns a zero. I'd like to embed vlookup in a function that, if vlookup finds a blank cell, returns a blank instead of a zero.

I don't want to have to type out:

`=if(vlookup(args) = "", "", vlookup(args))`

I would prefer to have something similar to the built in Iferror function whose syntax would be:

```
=blankreturn(function)
```

Which would return a blank if the function results in a blank, or the result of the function if it does not.

I have tried to define a custom function but it still returns a zero when it finds a blank cell

```
public Function Blankreturn(formula as variant)

If IsEmpty(formula) = True Then
   Blankreturn = ""
Else
   Blankreturn = formula
End if

End Function
```

Or even better, though I wouldn't know where to start with the code for this:

```
ifblank(function, "This is blank")
```

Which, if the first argument results in a blank, returns the second argument.

Thanks

Comment: That function does not return 0 if passed an empty cell as the argument, it returns "".

Comment: Do you specifically want this for `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: @Rory it returns a 0 if the indexed column is blank

Comment: If you pass a VLOOKUP formula to that UDF then yes it will return 0 because the VLOOKUP passed 0 to it. If the VLOOKUP result should be text, just use `=VLOOKUP(args)&""`.

Comment: @Rory Note that `=VLOOKUP(args)&""` will convert any number/date etc into a string too.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I did say "if the result should be text"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build your special [VLookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup) function

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MyVLookup(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Optional Arg4 = True)
    MyVLookup = Application.VLookup(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4)
    If VarType(MyVLookup) = 0 Then MyVLookup = vbNullString
End Function
```

[image]

But possibly using a VBA user definde function is slower than using this method `=if(vlookup(args) = "", "", vlookup(args))` I could imagine (would need to be tested).